# Bounds of a picture box inside a panel not updating when the panel is moved

Tags: c#

I am creating a side scrolling platform game in c#. This is done by moving a panel containing several picture boxes all with the same tag. The player can sit on top of these platforms. This all works perfectly until the panel moves. When it moves the bounds of the picture boxes no longer align with their actual location meaning the character falls through the visible platform but will be able to stand on the invisible place it was formerly in. Can the bounds not change from their original location or is there something that should be added to the code to update them?

Comment: So, does the Pbox move at all?

Comment: yes the picture box moves as its inside the panel, but its bounds dont follow it

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Of course the [Bounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) will not change as the size doesn't change and the loaction (__relative to the parent__, ie the panel !!) doesn't either! You may have to add the panel's location to get what you want.. Use [offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142187(v=vs.110).aspx) for this